# Initial two frames gives error INFO_OUTPT_FORMAT_CHNAGED & INFO_OUTPT_BUFFER_CHNAGED, so the respective frames cannot be rendered

Tags: android, decoding, android-mediacodec

I am using Android MediaCodec Api for decoding frames coming from a remote continuously.
When i feed these frames to decoder, initial two frames cannot be rendered & the respective index value is -3, -2.(INFO_OUTPT_FORMAT_CHNAGED, INFO_OUTPT_BUFFER_CHNAGED).

I want to render the very first frame to surface, please look into the code.

```
  public void init(int width, int height, Surface surface) {
    mPts = 0;
    format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(FORMAT, width, height);
    mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    mDecoder.start();
}
public void init(int width, int height, Surface surface) {
    mPts = 0;
    format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(FORMAT, width, height);
    mDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(sps));
    //format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(pps));
    mDecoder.start();
}
  public void decodeSample(byte[] data) {
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, Arrays.toString(data));
        int index = mDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT);
        Log.e(TAG, index + "");

        if (index >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mDecoder.getInputBuffer(index);
            if (buffer != null) {
                buffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
                mDecoder.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, data.length, mPts, 0);
            }
        }
        mPts++;

        int outIndex = mDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 1000000);
        Log.e(TAG, "decodeSample: " + outIndex);

        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "ready to render.....");
        mDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception*********: " + exception.getMessage());
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception*********: " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider init() method one time only.

Answer (score 0):

In the synchronous mode `dequeueOutputBuffer` can return a value that is a signal and not a buffer index. For example: `INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`, `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`.

This is okay, you are not loosing a frame. There is no decoded frame at the moment, and you are not supposed to release the buffer.

See the example in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#synchronous-processing-using-buffers).